# React native - should I use async storage or cookies?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, asyncstorage

I want to save a simple persisted property. If I was using native code I would have used User Definition in iOS and Shared Preferences in Android. As I understand the library async storage does that exactly.

So when should I use cookie and when should I user async storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies have a 4 kb capacity limit, and cookies are sent to the server with each server request.

The difference between `cookies` and `localStorage` is the permanence of the data. Of course, `cookies` can be used like `localStorage` with a long time limit. But it's not a good way and it doesn't fit the reason for using `cookies`.

First, cookies have api that uses cookie data on both the server side and the client side. In contrast, localStorage is controlled only in the local environment. For this reason, consider whether the stored cookie data is being written to both sides, and if server side usage is essential and frequent, it may be better to use more effective cookie values for non-local storage interaction with clients and servers.

You can store the data we need constantly (such as automatic login) on `localStorage`, and the information we need for a moment (such as one-time login information) on `cookies`. But never save important information such as passwords! You can always be robbed because you save it to the client.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. In React native, when persisting a cookie and then doing an ajax request, the cookie will be sent to the server? The react native app acts like a browser in that sense?

Comment: @Rotem It does not send the cookies it has when it communicates with the server. The cookies you want to use are managed within the React-native. This is different from the cookies used by the ajax server.

Comment: ok so this is exactly why I've asked the question. As for now I understand that the different is 4K limit and the time limit. Is that right?

Comment: That's right, the difference between capacity and time.